# Use TagBuilder in webform project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reference, webforms

I have a old webform project that I have now set to .net 4.0. I have added the System.Web.MVC ref 4.0 but the TabBuilder do still not show up as a known type?

Edit : I have also tried adding System.Web.WebPages 2.0 but that do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please test this code and see [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs) maybe you forget using

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication1.Helpers
{
    public static class ImageHelper
    {
        public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText)
        {
            return Image(helper, id, url, alternateText, null);
        }

        public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            // Create tag builder
            var builder = new TagBuilder("img");

            // Create valid id
            builder.GenerateId(id);

            // Add attributes
            builder.MergeAttribute("src", url);
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);
            builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

            // Render tag
            return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hmm I added the usings and it works? Usually this will be done automaticly by the inline popup. Thanks!